# Accesing ContentProviders data from another application in android

Tags: android

I have ContentProvider with database in one application and I inserted some data in to database.

Now i want to access the database data from another application through ContentProviders.

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

set `android:exported="true"` on your content provider declaration in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Actually it should be true by default, according to the documentation so in order to access it you'd only have to use the Uri of your ContentProvider?